# Laravel on Windows 10 WSL net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, windows, laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Maybe somebody knows why and how to fix it:

To develop a Laravel application I setup WSL on Windows 10 with PHP (7.0.12 via ppa:ondrej/php) including all required dependencies. 
Then I try to run the application with:

```
php artisan serve
```

The HTML part is delivered consistently to the browser, while the assets not. 
Sometimes they are served, sometimes I get:

[image: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

As well as:

[image: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

Am I able to fix that somehow?

Comment: Is WSL really ready to do such things consistently? Wouldn't  Homestead serve you better for Laravel development? I'm running Vagrant/Homestead/Putty on a Windows 10 and it's a breeze.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I could go with Homestead. But I don't want to for some reason :)

Comment: Have you checked apache logs why the request was not processed?

Comment: Yep (php_error.log), but there is no error.